# Initialising a dynamic length character array in a typdef struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I define a `struct` inside a header file which looks similar to:

```
#define BUFSIZE (500)

typedef struct container {
   int file_descriptor;
   char file_content[BUFSIZE];
}container;
```

Now, I want to have a variable BUFSIZE, such that the total characters that `file_content` can hold, reflects that. How could I make `file_content` a variable-sized character buffer array? It can be around 30-50KB. If I initialize it with 50KB, I will get the stack overflow error.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to learn dynamic memory usage, and "malloc" the necessary memory.

### Example:

```
#define BUFSIZE (50*1024)  // 50KBytes.
int main(void)
{
    container my_container; // Error: Stack Overflow

    container*  correct_container = NULL;
    correct_container = malloc(sizeof(container)); // No StackOverflow: should succeed.

   correct_container->file_descriptor = get_fd();
   memset(correct_container->file_content, 0, BUFSIZE);

   // After usage is done.
   free(correct_container);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `struct` may have a **flexible array member** as its last member.  In your case it would look like this:

```
typedef struct container {
   int file_descriptor;
   char file_content[];
}container;
```

The size of the `struct` is (roughly speaking) the size has the last element been omitted.  You can then dynamically allocate an instance of this struct with as much room as needed for the last member.  For example:

```
container *mycontainer = malloc(sizeof(*mycontainer) + 50000);
```

Also, because the size of the struct can vary in this way, it may not be a member of an array or of another `struct` or `union`.

Comment: `50000` is OK, but `sizeof *mycontainer)+  sizeof mycontainer->file_content * 50000` is more informative.  UV for FAM